# Wix webhooks - why is my Callback URL action method not being called after an event in Wix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webhooks, actionmethod, velo

I'm developing a Wix dashboard app, and I'm trying to use the Wix webhooks, so that Wix will make a call to our server when certain actions occur in the dashboard app (like installing the app i.e. the 'Provision - provision' event, removing the app, or a billing action like upgrading within Wix).

I've added a Server Component to our app, and I've chosen the events to register to.

When I then perform an app install or uninstall in the app, there is no call made to our MVC action method that's supposed to handle the webhook. The Server Component Callback URL is set to this url on our test server:

https://host/Webhook/ProcessWebhookEvent?vendorId=Wix​

... and the signature of the .NET MVC action method that this points to is:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("ProcessWebhookEvent")]
public HttpStatusCodeResult ProcessWebhookEvent(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] string requestBody, string vendorId, string eventType = "Unknown")
{
```

When I test this by making a 'GET' request using the Callback URL (https://host/Webhook/ProcessWebhookEvent?vendorId=Wix​), the Action Method is successfully called.

If I perform one of the actions on the app however, that's supposed to trigger a webhook request (like adding or removing the app from Wix), then the Action Method isn't called. I've tried adding an 'HttpPost' attribute to the Action Method, but it makes no difference.

Why am I not seeing any calls from the Wix webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. This turned out to be a firewall issue that for some reason was blocking the requests from Wix.